# ¿Por qué el método destroy no funciona si tengo paginación en Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, php7

Uso PHP 7.0.33 y Laravel 5.5

Dentro de mi controlador tengo los métodos para el CRUD. (Aquí sólo pondré 2).

```
public function index()
    {
                $plants = Plant::latest()->paginate(15);
                return view('plants.index', compact('plants'));
    }

public function destroy(Plant $plant)
    {
                $plant->delete();
                return redirect()->route('plants.index')->with('status', 'Plant deleted!');
    }
```

El problema es que, cuando estoy en el show() y ejecuto el destroy funciona correctamente, pero cuando estoy en el index (el listado) no me funciona (me sigue mostrando que se eliminó con éxito pero de la lista no se borra y si refresco la página sigue ahí). Esto me hace pensar que quizás esa paginación hace algo que no tiene que hacer ¿me pueden ayudar?.

Aclaraciones: Si hay menos de 15 registros (o sea, no hay paginación) el eliminar funciona correctamente.

Comment: En tu función destroy cuando envías desde el listado, verificas que llegue correctamente la planta `$plant`?

Comment: Lo verificaré y te diré unas horas. Gracias por tomarte la molestía de comentar